# pivot rows to columns and retain one row for one user

Tags: sql, sql-server, group-by, pivot, row

| id | user | manager_id | manager_name | hierarchy | level_1 | level_2 | level_3 | level_4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 100 | A | 30 | peter | 1 | brian | null | null | null |
| 100 | A | null | null | 2 | null | koby | null | null |
| 100 | A | null | null | 3 | null | null | peter | null |
| 200 | B | 20 | koby | 1 | null | brian | null | null |
| 200 | B | null | null | 2 | peter | null | null | null |
| 200 | B | null | null | 3 | null | null | koby | null |
| 300 | C | 10 | brian | 1 | peter | null | null | null |
| 300 | C | null | null | 2 | null | koby | null | null |
| 300 | C | null | null | 3 | null | null | brian | null |

How to pivot the rows values to existing columns so as to retain one row for one user?

| id | user | manager_id | manager_name | hierarchy | level_1 | level_2 | level_3 | level_4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 100 | A | 30 | peter | 4 | brian | koby | peter | null |
| 200 | B | 20 | koby | 4 | peter | brian | koby | null |
| 300 | C | 10 | brian | 4 | peter | koby | brian | null |

Note: Each level will have only one value for each user.

Comment: Please always show the complete sample input and complete expected result when asking SQL questions!

Comment: Is this data always in this form for your entire table or can multiple columns per row be filled rather than be null? What to do in this case?

Comment: if a user does not have a level_4 entry then it will be NULL.

Comment: This should mean a user can never have a not null value in more than one column?

Comment: no, a user is allowed to have as many non-null values as there are number of rows per user. user A in the above example has values for level_1, level_2,level_3 and no value for level_4, if there was another column called level_5 then that values would be NULL as well

Comment: We're not talking about different "*level_n*" fields. What we're trying to say is "can a user have different values in different records for the same level_1 field?" If the answer is no, you need simple aggregation. If the answer is yes, you need to specify details on how this specific case should be addressed.

Comment: no, one record per level. i.e., level_1 will have only one value and level_2 will have only one value and so on.

Comment: How do you generate your "*hierarchy*" field? It seems it's not following specific rules during the aggregation...

Comment: the way i obtained the above input table is from a recursive sql query, which for a level_4 employee breaks down the values into 3 rows as hierarchy = 1, 2 and 3 and assigns the respective leaders. so level 4 employee would have 3 rows and a level 5 employee would have 4 rows and so on.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given your premise of one single value on aggregated fields for each user, you can just use aggregation with the `MAX` funtion for each non-aggregated field:

```
SELECT id, [user], 
       MAX(manager_id)   AS manager_id, 
       MAX(manager_name) AS manager_name, 
       MAX(hierarchy) +1 AS hierarchy,
       MAX(level_1)      AS level_1, 
       MAX(level_2)      AS level_2, 
       MAX(level_3)      AS level_3, 
       MAX(level_4)      AS level_4 
FROM tab
GROUP BY id, [user]
```

Check the demo [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/-yc04PRj).

Comment: this doesn't give the expected results. i tried the above method of pivoting, i still have 3 rows per user.

Comment: This is the working SQL Fiddle: https://dbfiddle.uk/R7WztsvV. Can you replicate what you tried in this fiddle?

Comment: i tried the above code but doesn't result in he same output as your code. there are few more column in the original data which i didn't add because it's not used for pivot. would that make a difference?

Comment: You should add every non-aggregated field into your `GROUP BY` clause, and follow Jonas suggestion.

Comment: i have updated the table to reflect the actual data format

Comment: catch the differences in the updated answer

Comment: updated the expected answer table

Comment: Compare the fiddle's schema with your table schema. If you catch differences, point them out. @usr367

Comment: max should be on every column EXCEPT ID and ID should be the only `group by` object. [Example](https://dbfiddle.uk/HoqsDQco)

Comment: There's a new issue with the updated data (involves the hierarchy field), I guess I need to retune this query. Thanks for pointing!

Answer (score 0):

I would use `STRING_AGG` here because I dislike the risk to lose data if multiple levels per row are `NOT NULL` or a user has multiple names per level in different rows.

If this doesn't happen, the result is the same as when using `MAX` or `MIN`.

If it does happen, we will get every name per level instead of one only.

```
SELECT id, 
MAX(user_id) AS user_id, 
MAX(manager_id) AS manager_id, 
MAX(manager_name) AS manager_name, 
MAX(hierarchy) +1 AS hierarchy, 
STRING_AGG(level_1,',') AS level_1,
STRING_AGG(level_2,',') AS level_2,
STRING_AGG(level_3,',') AS level_3,
STRING_AGG(level_4,',') AS level_4  
FROM yourtable
GROUP BY id;
```

Replicate the difference here: [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/vcMWZ3HS)

Even considering your statement there is always one name per level only, I would not risk that. In a week or a month, things might differ.

Sidenote: I renamed "user" to "user_id" in my example because I refuse to use SQL key words as column name or table name. I recommend to avoid that if not urgently necessary.

Comment: i am not sure what i am missing, i am following your code to the T, but i am not getting the expected results. i am still getting 3 rows per user

Comment: sorry my bad, i have updated my input table to reflect the changes. the hierarchy pertains to the user.

Comment: That's a completely new situation now and the question has nothing to do with the original one. Please undo these changes, accept an answer (upvote the other if you like) and create a new question. If you change your question everytime after a correct answer has already been provided, this will be a never ending story and no one will be able to replicate this.

Comment: thanks for your suggestion. i will post a new question

Comment: @usr367 Updated the answer according to your new requirements, please check again.

Comment: this answer works! i marked the answer as accepted.

Comment: You're welcome, but I'm not lemon ;)

Comment: haha thanks Jonas Metzler!!